# Help creating a single SELECT statement for SQL Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select, group-by

I am trying to create an payment report which lists the sum in each account.
The table is in SQL SERVER 2005 and it has the following table

[Account]     [Amount]   [Type]

1111         10         C

1111         10         C

1111         15         D

1111         5          D

1112         10         C

1112         15         C

1112         10         D

1112         10         D

I need to create report that will sum the Credit and Debit for each account
Output

1111     0

1112     5

Is there a single SELECT statement that I can use to generate the output? I can do this by creating temp tables but I was wondering if I can do it in a single SELECT statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select Account, 
    sum(case when Type='D' then Amount * -1 else Amount end) as AmountSum
from Payment
group by Account
```

Comment: @James - In that case you should select the tick mark to the left of this answer to mark it as the accepted answer.